# change event not perform on datepicker through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass a selected date to controller for performing operation on database.

But my jquery is not functioning properly..
Can anyone help me solve the issue?

here is my View code :

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "PRC Date", Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

here is my jQuery Code..

```
$("#DT").on("change", function () {
            debugger
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            alert(selectedValue);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("DateWiseData", "ProcessWax")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: selectedValue,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status == true) {
                        alert('Successfully done.');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Failed');
                    }
                },
                //error: function () { alert('Error. Please try again.'); }
            });
        });
```

Comment: This code shuold work, but maybe you were looking for `input` event instead of `change`?

Comment: yep..may be you are right ..but how to do it.?

Comment: Try changing the first line of jquery code:

 `$("#DT").on("input", function () {`

Comment: no its not working..:(

Comment: How exactly is your jquery not working? Nothing is being passed to your controller?

Comment: no nothing is passed to my controller ...because change event is not invoke than how data pass to controller.?

Comment: if change event is performing than through ajax ..data pass to controller...

Answer (score 0):

If you want that select a date from Jquery datepicker and send it to your controller you can simply bind your datepicker to your controller.

HTML :

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{      

    <div class="form-group">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "PRC Date", Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div> 

    <button type="submit"></button>
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(YourModel t)
    {
        var date = t.DT;
        //Do whatever you want (ex. save in database)
        return View();
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

Please Try this code:

```
$( function() {
             $( "#DT" ).datepicker()
                .on("change", function () {

                    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                    alert(selectedValue);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '@Url.Action("DateWiseData", "ProcessWax")',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: selectedValue,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.status == true) {
                                alert('Successfully done.');
                            }
                            else {
                                alert('Failed');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
    } );
```

As you can see in the code you forgot to put *.datepicker()* after *$("#DT")* .

Comment: i want to perform change event of date-picker because i want to perform operation every time when date is changed.but my change event is not working so how can i do that ?

Comment: I am sorry for my misunderstanding. @manishpatat Please check the Update.

Comment: you should add these links: 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "PRC Date", Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() } })
</div>
```

jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script>
        alert();
        $("#DT").on("change", function () {
                var selectedValue = $(this).val();
                alert(selectedValue);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                  url: "/ProcessWax/DateWiseData?Date=" + selectedValue ,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: selectedValue,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.status == true) {
                            alert('Successfully done.');
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Failed');
                        }
                    },
                    //error: function () { alert('Error. Please try again.'); }
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult DateWiseData(DateTime Date)
  {

  }
```

Comment: put this line before <script>tag   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Comment: check alert coming or not

Comment: i am edited jquery section in answer, copy and paste on your page and check alert is coming or not on page load

Comment: change  $("#DT").on("change", function () line to  $(".datepicker").on("change", function ()

Comment: i change line what u say..but still not giving alert with selectedDate ..

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> put this line before code, check updated answer in jquery section